# capturing rfid reading from arduino to android application using usb cable

Tags: java, android, arduino

I am working on an android application that receives rfid reading from Arduino MEGA 2560. This is the code for my android app

```
package com.example.halfway;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;

public class Violation extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.google.android.DemoKit.action.USB_PERMISSION";
    private UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
    private boolean mPermissionRequestPending;
    private UsbAccessory mAccessory;
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor;
    private FileInputStream mInputStream;
    private FileOutputStream mOutputStream;

    EditText name,add,vnum,lnum;
    Button one;
    CheckBox a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_violation);
        setupAccessory();


        name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        add =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add);
        vnum =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.plate_no);
        lnum =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.license_no);
        a=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sec1_a);
        b=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_b);
        c=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_c);
        d=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_d);
        e=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_e);
        f=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_f);
        g=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_g);
        h=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_h);
        i=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_i);
        j=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_j);
        k=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_k);
        l=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_l);
        m=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_m);
        n=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_n);
        o=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_o);
        p=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_p);
        q=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_q);
        r=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_r);
        t=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_t);
        u=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_u);
        v=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_v);
        w=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_w);
        x=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_x);
        y=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_y);
        z=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sec1_z);
        one =(Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(view==one){
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {
                    name.setError("Text field is empty");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(add.getText().toString())) {
                    add.setError("Text field is empty");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(vnum.getText().toString())) {
                    vnum.setError("Text field is empty");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lnum.getText().toString())) {
                    lnum.setError("Text field is empty");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuilder violations= new StringBuilder(40);
                violations.append("Sec1 ");
                if(a.isChecked()){
                    violations.append("a");
                }
                if(b.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",b");
                }
                if(c.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",c");
                }
                if(d.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",d");
                }
                if(e.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",e");
                }
                if(f.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",f");
                }
                if(g.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",g");
                }
                if(h.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",h");
                }
                if(i.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",i");
                }
                if(j.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",j");
                }
                if(k.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",k");
                }
                if(l.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",l");
                }
                if(m.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",m");
                }
                if(n.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",n");
                }
                if(o.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",o");
                }
                if(p.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",p");
                }
                if(q.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",q");
                }
                if(r.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",r");
                }
                if(t.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",t");
                }
                if(u.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",u");
                }
                if(v.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",v");
                }
                if(w.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",w");
                }
                if(x.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",x");
                }
                if(y.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",y");
                }
                if(z.isChecked()){
                    violations.append(",z");
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Violation.this, VerifyActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fname", name.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("address", add.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("vnumber", vnum.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("violation", violations.toString());
                intent.putExtra("lnumber", lnum.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                }}
            });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (mAccessory != null) {
            return mAccessory;
        } else {
            return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        if (mInputStream != null && mOutputStream != null) {
            //streams were not null");
            return;
        }
        //streams were null");
        UsbAccessory[] accessories = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
        UsbAccessory accessory = (accessories == null ? null : accessories[0]);
        if (accessory != null) {
            if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(accessory)) {
                openAccessory(accessory);
            } else {
                synchronized (mUsbReceiver) {
                    if (!mPermissionRequestPending) {
                        mUsbManager.requestPermission(accessory, mPermissionIntent);
                        mPermissionRequestPending = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // null accessory
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ValueMsg t = (ValueMsg) msg.obj;
            // this is where you handle the data you sent. You get it by calling the getReading() function
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add);
            editText.setText(""+t.getReading(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
    };


    private void setupAccessory() {
        UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mPermissionIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            mAccessory = (UsbAccessory) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            openAccessory(mAccessory);
        }
    }
    private void openAccessory(UsbAccessory accessory) {
        mFileDescriptor = mUsbManager.openAccessory(accessory);
        if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
            mAccessory = accessory;
            FileDescriptor fd = mFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
            mInputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);
            mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fd);
            Thread thread = new Thread(null, this, "OpenAccessoryTest");
            thread.start();
            //Accessory opened
        } else {
            // failed to open accessory
        }
    }

    private void closeAccessory() {
        try {
            if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
                mFileDescriptor.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            mFileDescriptor = null;
            mAccessory = null;
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        int ret = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        int i;

        while (true) { // read data
            try {
                ret = mInputStream.read(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            i = 0;
            while (i < ret) {
                int len = ret - i;
                if (len >= 1) {
                    Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler);
                    int TagSerialNumber = (int)buffer[i];
                    // 'f' is the flag, use for your own logic
                    // value is the value from the arduino
                    m.obj = new ValueMsg('f', TagSerialNumber);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(m);
                }
                i += 4; // number of bytes sent from arduino
            }

        }
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        openAccessory(accessory);
                    } else {
                        // USB permission denied
                    }
                }
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                if (accessory != null && accessory.equals(mAccessory)) {
                    //accessory detached
                    closeAccessory();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.violation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is the code of my arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>  // Include of the RC522 Library
#include <SPI.h>  // Used for communication via SPI with the Module
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>

#define SDAPIN 53  // RFID Module SDA Pin is connected to the UNO 10 Pin
#define RESETPIN 5 // RFID Module RST Pin is connected to the UNO 8 Pin

AndroidAccessory acc("Manufacturer",
         "Model",
         "Description",
         "1.0",
         "http://yoursite.com",
         "0000000012345678");

byte FoundTag;  // Variable used to check if Tag was found
byte ReadTag;  // Variable used to store anti-collision value to read Tag information
byte TagData[MAX_LEN];  // Variable used to store Full Tag Data
byte TagSerialNumber[5];  // Variable used to store only Tag Serial Number
byte GoodTag1SerialNumber[5] = {0x7D, 0x60, 0x9B, 0xC};  //  The Tag Serial number we are looking for
byte GoodTag2SerialNumber[5] = {0x39, 0xC, 0x56, 0x84};  //  The Tag Serial number we are looking for

MFRC522 nfc(SDAPIN, RESETPIN);  // Init of the library using the UNO pins declared above

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  acc.powerOn();

// Start to find an RFID Module
  Serial.println("Looking for RFID Reader");
  nfc.begin();
  byte version = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();  // Variable to store Firmware version of the Module

// If can't find an RFID Module  
  if (! version) {  
    Serial.print("Didn't find RC522 board.");
    while(1); //Wait until a RFID Module is found
  }

// If found, print the information about the RFID Module
  Serial.print("Found chip RC522 ");
  Serial.print("Firmware version: 0x");
  Serial.println(version, HEX);
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {

  String GoodTag1="False";  // Variable used to confirm good Tag Detected
  String GoodTag2="False";  // Variable used to confirm good Tag Detected

// Check to see if a Tag was detected
// If yes, then the variable FoundTag will contain "MI_OK"
  FoundTag = nfc.requestTag(MF1_REQIDL, TagData);

  if (FoundTag == MI_OK) {
    delay(200);

// Get anti-collision value to properly read information from the Tag
    ReadTag = nfc.antiCollision(TagData);

    memcpy(TagSerialNumber, TagData, 4);  // Write the Tag information in the TagSerialNumber variable

    if (acc.isConnected()) 
  {
    acc.write(TagSerialNumber, 4);
    }
    Serial.println("Tag detected.");
    Serial.print("Serial Number:  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  // Loop to print serial number to serial monitor
      Serial.print(TagSerialNumber[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println();

// Check if detected Tag has the right Serial number we are looking for   
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
      if (GoodTag1SerialNumber[i] != TagSerialNumber[i]) {
        break;  // if not equal, then break out of the "for" loop
      }
      if (i == 3) {  // if we made it to 4 loops then the Tag Serial numbers are matching
       GoodTag1="TRUE";
      }
     } 
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
      if (GoodTag2SerialNumber[i] != TagSerialNumber[i]) {
        break;  // if not equal, then break out of the "for" loop
      }
      if (i == 3) {  // if we made it to 4 loops then the Tag Serial numbers are matching
       GoodTag2="TRUE";
      } 
    }

  }
}
```

please tell me what is wrong with my code and what should i edit for it to work.
any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are never instantiating mUsbManager properly. You are creating a local variable instead of initializing the class variable.

```
    private void setupAccessory() {
        UsbManager mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE); // <--- This should not be local!
        // Your other code....
    }
```

Comment: my app can be launched now thank you. but i don't receive any data from it, what else am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you handling permission requests at?

Comment: <activity
  android:name=".Violation"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_violation" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter"/>
</activity>
        <uses-library android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"></uses-library>

Comment: Are you capturing the events in the cases where usb permissions were denied or where you are trying to open the device? If so, what are the messages you are getting back?

Comment: the device is already open. i am trying to capture a hexadecimal rfid reading from the arduino mega to be used in my android application